# How to select vendor prefix with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We can customize vendor specific css. Example below:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But the same selector if used with jquery it won't work:

```
$('::-webkit-scrollbar').css({backgroundColor:'red');
```

So, how can we select vendor specific selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, per se. You can only select *elements* not pseudo-elements.

The scrollbar doesn't have a `style` attribute to modify.

If you want to modify its CSS then you need to write a CSS rule for it.

You could do that with JavaScript via [the Stylesheet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) or you could write the rules into the stylesheet and then activate them by adding a `class` to an element.

The latter approach is likely to be the simpler.

```js
document
    .querySelector("button")
    .addEventListener( 
        "click", 
        event =>
            document
                .querySelector(".foo")
                .classList
                .toggle("bar") 
);
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 5em;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  border: grey outset 3px;
}

.bar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>

<button>click me</button>
```